# compare record <= and >= near mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My question is compare the record between <= and >= my table contain columns ID,Name,Address,Stacks,StartDateTime,EndDateTime. I want to fetch record between StartDateTime and EndDateTime. DateTime Format is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
mysql-> Select * from Table_nm where  StartDateTime>= $DATETIME and EndDateTime<= $DATETIME1;
```

But If suppose `$DATETIME="2015-02-03 10:00:00";` And `$DATETIME1=NULL`
 Then How will I search a record for above query.It search record whoes value NULL.
and It work for where  `StartDateTime>= $DATETIME and EndDateTime<= $DATETIME1;` ??
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IFNULL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) function like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_nm 
WHERE StartDateTime >= $DATETIME 
AND   EndDateTime <= IFNULL($DATETIME1, '2020-12-31');
```

IFNULL will check if your `$DATETIME1` is null then it will pick up date ad 31st December 2020 (You can advance further as well, this was just an example.)

Comment: date 2020-12-31 this date why?

Comment: and Date time contain (DATE, TIME )

Comment: as i said, its just an example of future date you could select any date. By default it will take 12 AM in the morning as time.

Comment: CAN I TAKE IT 2036-12-31 and For time?

Comment: fine it will take 12 AM as i said in comment above, so try it.

Comment: Meance, no need to Time  right? It takes default value 12 AM . but my dateformat 00:00:00 so it will take this format ?sorry I asking so many silly question.